# VSC config "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true have no effect

Tags: javascript, eslint, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am using eslint and prettier , also them extensions . The problem is that I cant ommit the vsc config what remove the space between function name and parenthesis

elsint (standar) fix like this

```
function Name () {}
```

prettier (extension) fix like this

```
function Name() {}
```

I know "editor.formatOnSave": true, can solve the problem

but this doesnt format the code so i need to format manualy ... (ctrl + shift + i)